# Close Modal - Ionic 4 using Angular

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular8

I had created a page reservation.page.ts in which i want to make a modal form using ionic 4. 
i'm using ionic modal controller for that.
the example code which i did is

```
async closeModal() {
    await this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
}
```

still my modal is didn't work.

it gives an error like

```
core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): overlay does not exist
    at resolvePromise (VM11170 polyfills.js:3803)
    at VM11170 polyfills.js:3713
    at rejected (VM11177 vendor.js:129666)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (VM11170 polyfills.js:3365)
    at Object.onInvoke (VM11177 vendor.js:71868)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (VM11170 polyfills.js:3364)
    at Zone.run (VM11170 polyfills.js:3130)
    at VM11170 polyfills.js:3861
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM11170 polyfills.js:3397)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (VM11177 vendor.js:71849)
```

so please help me out.

Comment: Refer this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problems-to-close-modal-ionic-4/151372/12

Comment: Did you import viewCtrl as ModalController? No need to use async, just dismiss

Answer (score 1):

Use `ModalController` to dismiss the modal instead of the old `ViewController` implementation.

Open modal

```js
async openModal() {
  const modal = await this.modalController.create({
    component: Page
  });

  return await modal.present();
}
```

Close modal on Page

```js
close() {
  this.modalController.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by declaring the variable modal and then using it to close the modal:

```js
export class BlaBlaPage implements OnInit {

modal:any;

close() {
  this.modal.dismiss();
}
```